# How to apply different fancyhdr pagestyles across multiple pages

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have the following file structure:

```shell
my_doc
├── Pages
│   ├── blankPage.tex
│   ├── Page1.tex
│   └── Page2.tex
├── customPreamble.sty
└── main_file.tex
```

I have placed all the `\usepackage{}` calls in the `.sty` file. The problem is as follows:

I have defined three `\fancypagestyle{}` within the **customPreamble.sty** file. In the **main_file.tex** I begin by using the `\pagestyle{empty}` call. Then I include the **Page1.tex** and the **Page2.tex** via `\input{]` calls.

In each page, I have defined at the top of the page:

```latex
\pagestyle{stylename}
```

Now, the compilation via `xelatex` is working fine, without any explicit errors, but, the pagestyles are not fully getting applied

How to fix this?

All files are attached below:

**customPreamble.sty**

```latex
\usepackage[outer=0.6in,headheight=77pt,top=3cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}%{0.75pt}
\definecolor{headerYellow}{rgb}{0.96, 0.78, 0.36}
\definecolor{greyShade}{RGB}{0,20,20} % Color of the boxes behind the abstract and headings

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
{
    \Large% %change this size to your needs for the first line
    \bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{14pt}{%
    \Large %change this size to your needs for the second line
}
\titleformat*{\section}{\large\headingfont} 

\hypersetup{
    %bookmarks=true,    % show bookmarks bar?
    pdftitle={blah},    % title
    pdfauthor={blah},                     % author
    pdfsubject={blah},                        % subject of the document
    pdfkeywords={blah}, % list of keywords
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=blue,       % color of internal links
    citecolor=black,       % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=black,        % color of file links
    urlcolor=blue,        % color of external links
    linktoc=page            % only page is linked
} %
\def\myversion{0.0.1}
\date{\today}

\addto\captionsenglish{
    \renewcommand\listfigurename{Table of Figures}
    \renewcommand\listtablename{Table of Tables}
}


%% Setting the Header and Footer for all pages

\fancypagestyle{myblank}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyhead[L]{}
    \fancyhead[C]{}        %[CO, CE]
    \fancyhead[R]{}   %[RO, RE]
    
    \fancyfoot[L]{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{}
    
    \renewcommand{\headrule}{}
    \renewcommand{\footrule}{}
}

\fancypagestyle{mytitle}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}

    \fancyhead[L]{}
    \fancyhead[C]{\slshape \rightmark}        %[CO, CE]
    \fancyhead[R]{\textbf{LOGO}}   %[RO, RE]
    
    \fancyfoot[L]{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{{\small \copyright \the\year{}, Org\textsuperscript \textregistered, Inc. All Rights Reserved.}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage}
    
    \renewcommand{\headrule}
    {
        \hrule height 1pt
        \vspace{0.5pt}
        \hrule height 3pt
    }
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{}

\fancypagestyle{myregular}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}

    \fancyhead[L]{}
    \fancyhead[C]{
        \fbox{\parbox[b][][b]{10cm}{
                \begin{center}
                    %\vspace{-10pt}
                    {\small \textbf{Line 1}}\\
                    {\small \textbf{Line 2}}\\
                    {\small \textbf{Version \myversion}}
                    \vspace{-11pt}
                \end{center}
            }}
    }        %[CO, CE]
    \fancyhead[R]{\textbf{LOGO}}   %[RO, RE]

    \fancyfoot[L]{\textbf{WTF}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{{\small \copyright \the\year{}, Org\textsuperscript \textregistered, Inc. All Rights Reserved.}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage}
    
    \renewcommand{\headrule}
    {
        \hrule height 3pt
    }
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
}
```

**blankPage.tex**

```latex
\pagestyle{myblank}

\begin{center}
    \hspace*{\fill} \break
    \vspace{4in}

    \textit{This page has been intentionally left blank.}

\end{center}
```

**Page1.tex**

```latex
\pagestyle{mytitle}

%% Beginning to work on content

\newtcolorbox{gradbox}[1][]{
    freelance,
    frame code={},
    interior code={
    \fill[top color=greyShade!45,bottom color=greyShade!5,middle color=greyShade!15]
        (interior.north west) rectangle (interior.south east);
    }
    outer arc=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    nobeforeafter,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    top=0pt,bottom=0pt,
    #1
}

%% Creating the title Page Content
\begin{center}
    \hspace*{\fill} \break
    \vspace{4cm}

    {\Huge \textbf{Ovolune}}\\

    \vspace{1cm}
    {\LARGE \textbf{A Document}}\\
    
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\LARGE \textbf{Version \myversion}}\\
    
    \vspace{1.5cm}
    {\Large \textbf{\today}}\\

    \vspace{5.4cm}
    %\begin{center}
    \fbox{\parbox[b][][b]{\linewidth}{
            \begin{gradbox}{}
                \begin{center}
                    \vspace{0.75cm}
                    {\Large \textbf{Org\textsuperscript \textregistered, Inc.}}\\
                    {\small Line}\\
                    {\small line}\\
                    \vspace{8pt}
                    {\large Phone:} {\small 0}\\
                    {\large Fax:} {\small 0}\\
                    {\large Email:}\href{mailto:}{ovolune@org.com}\\
                    {\large website:}\href{www.org.com}{www.org.com}\\
                    \vspace{0.75cm}
                \end{center}
            \end{gradbox}
        }}

\end{center}
```

**Page2.tex**

```latex
\chapter*{Disclaimer}

\thispagestyle{myregular}
\vspace{-0.7cm}

\noindent Some Disclaimer. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit nisl elit, ut mollis quam tempor eget. Sed risus nisi, aliquet quis aliquam tincidunt, fringilla eu ante. Nulla vitae leo rutrum, fermentum turpis vel, mollis nisl. Maecenas quis nisi libero. Vivamus fringilla mauris ante, id sagittis nibh tincidunt in. Aenean posuere lectus magna, ac lobortis felis mattis sit amet. Cras vel hendrerit dolor. Duis a vulputate risus. Maecenas non augue vitae justo sollicitudin convallis. Donec facilisis dolor arcu, sed scelerisque magna auctor quis.
```

**main_file.tex**

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{customPreamble}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

%% Including the title page
\newpage
\input{Pages/Page1.tex}

%% Including a blank page
\newpage
\input{Pages/blankPage.tex}

%% Including the Disclaimer Chapter
\newpage
\input{Pages/Page2.tex}

%% Including a blank page
\newpage
\input{Pages/blankPage.tex}

%% Including the Disclaimer Chapter
\newpage
\input{Pages/Page2.tex}

\end{document}
```

---

**Update**

1. Converted from `scrreprt` (KOMA) class to `report` class
2. Modified the `plain` pagestyle so that `\chapter` picks up the new pagestyle

**Problem**

Most of the pagestyles are applied successfully, except the footrule under the pagestyle `myregular`.

[image]

Comment: you shouldn't need to `\import{Pages}{PageStyles.tex}` on every page (and it may give errors depending on how you defined  the page style) as you have provided no example, it is hard to debug.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added the source code files for general purview!

Comment: Also, to compile I am using the `xelatexmk` option under **tex-live** compiler. More specifically I am using VSCode under windows with James Yu's LaTex Workshop extension that generates the command `xelatex -no-pdf -recorder -output-directory="d:/my_doc"  "d:\my_doc\main_file.tex"`.

Comment: unrelated but never have `\\  ` at the end of a paragraph.

Comment: theer is nothing forcing your "page" files to be on separate pages, so they can't normally have separate oage styles, but your page styles should just be defined once, in your preamble not `\import` in each page. Note also `\chapter` sets a plain style in most document classes

Comment: Do you have a special reason for using `geometry` and `fancyhdr` in a KOMA class? Also, off-topic: you are loading `hyperref` too early and it might be better to pass `table` to `xcolor` rather than loading `color` and `colortbl` directly. At least, I find this to be less problematic with Ti*k*Z.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have made changes to the source code - added `\newpage` in each page and moved the style defs in the preamble `.sty` file. Two of the three styles are getting applied, but, not the last one! Any help?

Comment: @cfr I know how to use `geometry` and `fancyhdr` packages - the KOMA class came from a template and I did not bother to change that - I understand that the packages are not very compatible with KOMA class (`scrreprt`), but, I have to currently use that.

Comment: as I said. `\chapter` will apply a page style, also you still have  bad `\\ `  everywhere, don't ignore underfull hbox badness 10000 warnings.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, handled most problems, except a footrule is missing. Could you help me with that? There are no more `underfull hbox badness` warnings.

Comment: note `\large{Phone:} ` makes the rest of the document (or environment) large, not just `Phone:`   size commands do not take an argument. This is the same as `\large Phone: `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand and I made the changes, yet I am getting the same problem - the footer rule is missing on one of the pagestyles! See attached screen grab.

Answer (score 0):

Among the files I had posted in the question, I had to change the file called **customPreamble.sty** as follows:

```latex
\usepackage[outer=0.6in,headheight=77pt,top=3cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}%{0.75pt}
\definecolor{headerYellow}{rgb}{0.96, 0.78, 0.36}
\definecolor{greyShade}{RGB}{0,20,20} % Color of the boxes behind the abstract and headings

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
{
    \Large% %change this size to your needs for the first line
    \bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{14pt}{%
    \Large %change this size to your needs for the second line
}
\titleformat*{\section}{\large\headingfont}

\hypersetup{
    %bookmarks=true,    % show bookmarks bar?
    pdftitle={blah},    % title
    pdfauthor={blah},                     % author
    pdfsubject={blah},                        % subject of the document
    pdfkeywords={blah}, % list of keywords
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=blue,       % color of internal links
    citecolor=black,       % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=black,        % color of file links
    urlcolor=blue,        % color of external links
    linktoc=page            % only page is linked
} %
\def\myversion{0.0.1}
\date{\today}

\addto\captionsenglish{
    \renewcommand\listfigurename{Table of Figures}
    \renewcommand\listtablename{Table of Tables}
}


%% Setting the Header and Footer for all pages

\fancypagestyle{myblank}{
    \renewcommand{\headrule}{}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}

    \fancyhead[L]{}
    \fancyhead[C]{}        %[CO, CE]
    \fancyhead[R]{}   %[RO, RE]
    
    \fancyfoot[L]{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{}
}

\fancypagestyle{mytitle}{
    \renewcommand{\headrule}
    {
        \hrule height 1pt
        \vspace{0.5pt}
        \hrule height 3pt
    }
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}

    \fancyhead[L]{}
    \fancyhead[C]{\slshape \rightmark}        %[CO, CE]
    \fancyhead[R]{\textbf{LOGO}}   %[RO, RE]
    
    \fancyfoot[L]{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{{\small \copyright \the\year{}, Org\textsuperscript \textregistered, Inc. All Rights Reserved.}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{}

\fancypagestyle{myregular}{
    \renewcommand{\headrule}
    {
        \hrule height 3pt
    }
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot{}

    \fancyhead[L]{}
    \fancyhead[C]{
        \fbox{\parbox[b][][b]{10cm}{
                \begin{center}
                    %\vspace{-10pt}
                    {\small \textbf{Line 1}}\\
                    {\small \textbf{Line 2}}\\
                    {\small \textbf{Version \myversion}}
                    \vspace{-11pt}
                \end{center}
            }}
    }        %[CO, CE]
    \fancyhead[R]{\textbf{LOGO}}   %[RO, RE]

    \fancyfoot[L]{\textbf{WTF}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{{\small \copyright \the\year{}, Org\textsuperscript \textregistered, Inc. All Rights Reserved.}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage}
}
```

The change that made it work for me is as follows:

under the `\fancypagestyle{myblank}` I was supposed to set the `\footrulewidth` to **0pt**:

```
\renewcommand{\headrule}{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
```

The result is as follows (*this is what I wanted*):
[image]